# Laravel Unit Test separate database

Tags: database, laravel, unit-testing

Can somebody help me, how can i run my tests, but they will interact with database copy or a virtual database. I know, that i need to use phpunit.xml file, but how? Give me a example please.

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) Laravel offers many ways to work on your actual database for tests (e.g. https://laravel.com/docs/master/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test), and besides on your testing environment the database should be disposable anyway.

Comment: unit tests can run on a sqlite database, which is different from your default database. If you need dummy data to test on you can use database seeding feature.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a workaround for this.

In your config/database.php bellow mysql add:

```
'mysql_testing' => [
'driver' => 'mysql',
'host' => env('TESTING_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
'database' => env('TESTING_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
'username' => env('TESTING_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
'password' => env('TESTING_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix' => '',
'strict' => false,
],
```

And now in your .env add the values for:

```
TESTING_DB_HOST=localhost
TESTING_DB_DATABASE=homestead_testing
TESTING_DB_USERNAME=homestead
TESTING_DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Now you can run

```
php artisan migrate —database=mysql_testing
```

And the last thing - open your phpunit.xml file in the app folder and add this:

```
  <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql_testing"/>
```

Comment: perfect. this saved me a lot of time, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

return [

    // other stuff

    'default' => env('DB_DEFAULT', 'mysql'),

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite_testing' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

    ],

    // other stuff

];
```

For controller

```
public function createApplication()
    {
        putenv('DB_DEFAULT=sqlite_testing');

        $app = require __DIR__ . '/../../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        Artisan::call('migrate');
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Artisan::call('migrate:reset');
        parent::tearDown();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@pardeep in test\CreatesApplication trait there is just one function
add this putenv('DB_DEFAULT=sqlite_testing');